# New schemaFactory instance fails with Illegal Argument

Tags: java, xml, xsd

When setting up to validate an XML document my statements

```
String schemaLanguage = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(schemaLanguage);
```

fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
```

Any ideas on why this is, and what can be done?